# make a dataframe base on a rows and columns of another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

i have a a dataframe 'a' like this:

| A header | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| c2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| c3 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| c4 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 7 |
| c5 | 7 | 4 | 5 | 8 | 9 |

now, i want to make a dataframe based on previous dataframe with name 'b'.

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | c1 | 0 |
| c1 | c2 | 1 |
| c1 | c3 | 3 |
| c1 | c4 | 4 |
| c1 | c5 | 2 |
| c2 | c1 | 2 |
| c2 | c2 | 4 |
| c2 | c3 | 3 |
| c2 | c4 | 2 |
| c2 | c5 | 4 |
| c3 | c1 | 2 |
| c3 | c2 | 4 |
| c3 | c3 | 1 |
| c3 | c4 | 2 |
| c3 | c5 | 2 |
| c4 | c1 | 8 |
| c4 | c2 | 4 |
| c4 | c3 | 6 |
| c4 | c4 | 5 |
| c4 | c5 | 7 |
| c5 | c1 | 7 |
| c5 | c2 | 4 |
| c5 | c3 | 5 |
| c5 | c4 | 8 |
| c5 | c5 | 9 |

could you help me to make this second dataframe ?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: no. i could not find my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
a.stack().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.melt` function as follow:

```
pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['A header'], value_vars=['c1', 'c2','c3','c4','c5'])
```

you can check the documentation here : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html